# Type Mismatch, yet functional code

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is designed to identify the string "%" in any cell and, if present, identify it by colouring it yellow.

Interestingly it does actually work, but I keep getting the type mismatch error afterword specifically on the line:

```
If InStr(rngCell.Value, "%") > 0 Then
```

This is my full code below:

```
Public Sub Markerrorvalues()

Dim iWarnColor As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim vVal
Dim tRow

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("C1:C" & LR)
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    tRow = rngCell.Row
    If InStr(rngCell.Value, "%") > 0 Then
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
    Else
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tried replicating it but... it run smoothly, no errors :/ when are u getting the error?

Comment: Yup, works as expected for me too. Can you give us an example of the data you're running it on?

Comment: this does appear to be working if I remove a certain amount of rows beneath.. perhaps in column C there is something it is unhappy running the line:  If InStr(rngCell.Value, "%") > 0 Then

Comment: The answer is there was an error value in Column C. This was a string however yet it still doesn't like running the function on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some cells with error values (eg `#REF!`, `#DIV/0!` etc)

To filter these out, wrap your troublesome code inside a `Not IsError` conditional:

```
If Not IsError(rngCell.Value) Then 
    If InStr(rngCell.Value, "%") > 0 Then
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
    Else
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
EndIf
```

Comment: @user1717622: chris' answer is right; I clarified it a little bit for you.